# What are different types of online game formats besides Flash?

Tags: file-format, online

I am currently looking into making a website that hosts various online games and would like to support as many formats as possible no matter how obscure. I was wondering if anybody could inform me on what these different formats(Flash, JavaScript, etc.) may be and possibly even provide me with some insight on how to embed them.

Comment: This looks like Gorilla vs. Shark question to me.

Comment: Or a "Which technology" question

Comment: Well it's not a "gorilla vs. shark" question since he's not asking which is best, just which exist. One could argue that simply listing what technologies exist for this purpose is a really basic question, but I don't see anything wrong with basic questions so long as people refer to the existing answers instead of constantly asking it over and over.

Comment: As jhocking, this isn't a "which technology" question. I don't see what's wrong with it, and why it has been closed.

Answer (score 3):

By far the majority of browser-based games are done in Flash. However the newer and growing in importance game format is HTML5 (ie. games programmed in JavaScript that use the new Canvas element).

I've also seen many games that are pretty much just static images and web forms for the UI and the server simply constructs different static HTML pages in response to the player clicking on the buttons.

Up until recently Unity used to be another format for browser games. However the latest version of Unity actually deploys Flash content, making Unity games a special case of Flash games.

The only other format I can think of that has any impact whatsoever in browser games in Java, because that's what Puzzle Pirates used (and even that I'm not 100% sure about). That is a single game that came out years ago, hardly worth worrying about.

Comment: How exactly does one go about embedding an HTML5 canvas game?

Comment: As a portal for online games you would pretty much just provide an iframe that points to their game's URL. Unlike a Flash game, there's no single package like a .swf that you could host.

Comment: Well, in Java technically there's also Minecraft. Now everyone's playing it on the downloadable client, but on its early days, where only creative mode existed, playing on the online client was quite common I think (not that it matters if you're building a portal, anyway).

Comment: oh right, good point about Minecraft. I mean, the fact that it moved away from a browser-based client pretty quickly tells you a lot, but that is another very significant example of a browser-based game done in Java.

Comment: -1 suggesting Java and IMO missing the point of the question.

Comment: @Yannbane: You can't downvote someone because you don't like Java. The question asks about forms that online games take, and Java is one such form.

Comment: Maybe Silverlight, Microsofts failed attempt at replacing Flash, is also worth mentioning. Even though it is pretty dead, the OP said "as many formats as possible no matter how obscure".

Comment: @davey: regarding embedding a HTML5 canvas game: That's definitely worth opening a separate question. The security implications are especially tricky when you host 3rd party javascript applications, because all scripts and files which are served by the same domain are considered to be trusted by the domain and to trust each other.

Comment: RuneScape is in Java too. Java is big in browser games, like it or not.

Comment: @Kylotan: I actually like Java. However, it's very unsafe inside a browser, and many influential organizations, such as Mozilla, are suggesting people to disable it. Mentioning it as an option and not warning about its lack of security measures is dangerous, and therefore this answer should be downvoted. Refer to [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/27927) and its comments.

Comment: I mentioned it basically to dismiss it, saying "hardly worth worrying about". That's not exactly "suggesting" it. And that security thread (which is a good point) would have made your original comment more constructive.

Comment: @Yannbane: I know the security aspects, but that's not the issue here. Flash has had massive insecurities too but we still recommend that because it's popular. We're not here to tell the OP which games he should or shouldn't host when he asks for a list of formats. It's fine to mention the security aspect but it's not fine to say an answer isn't 'useful' when it's perfectly truthful and relevant.

Comment: The security issues are both fundamental, current, and big enough to at least ask the OP to mention them and suggest against Java as a browser gaming platform. Once again I like the language, and I don't believe desktop apps nor server software are affected, but browser games a pretty much a lost front.

Comment: Incidentally you never explained what you meant in the second part of your comment: "missing the point of the question".  It looks to me like the question asks for a list of technologies used to make browser games, so I listed technologies used to make browser games. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

There are many file formats that you can put online, like other than swf, there is java (which requires an application for webpage integration) and there are files that probably aren't official, like [scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) and [GameMaker](http://yoyogames.com/).  There is also Unity3d(http://unity3d.com/)  However, if you'd like to go to the most basic format, I would say that is javascript, other file formats probably require download.  But as I said, there are many other game engines for online integration.

But then again, Java is insecure, as we already know safari has blocked Java 7.

Good luck on your new site!

Comment: Again, -1 for suggesting Java. Refer to [this comment](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26130/what-are-different-types-of-online-game-formats-besides-flash/47804#comment79745_26132).

Comment: Dude, this question ask possible online game formats.  I suppose you think that minecraft is giving people errors, or android games?  Just dont downvote me cause you absolutely cant stand the name of Java

Comment: Wrong. Did you even follow that link? I love Java. Desktop, mobile and server applications are not affected, but using it to run random code you receive over a network is insecure and probably never will be, unless they place restrictions which they seem to be reluctant to do. -1 removed though, it's good that you've added that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Plug-in based:

- [Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer.html)
- [Shockwave Player](http://www.adobe.com/products/shockwaveplayer/)
- [Unity Web Player](http://unity3d.com/webplayer/)
- [Java applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet)
- [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/)
- [3DVIA Player](http://www.3dvia.com/products/3dvia-player/)

Others:

- [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) ([JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) + [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp), [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp), [CSS anims](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp)...)
- [Google Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/)
- [PHP/MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) + static HTML

Plug-in based technologies are easy to embed. Usually, a game will be packaged in a single file that will be served through HTML via a simple `<embed>` tag. That's the bright side, the dark side is that they're non-standard and thus aren't supported directly by browser vendors, and might require an extra download from your users.

That was the easy part, but plug-in based games are only one side the ecosystem. If you really want to support the widest possible spectrum you'll have to consider other things. HTML5-based solutions are hot today, they are standard, and they can prove worthwhile. But they will be much harder to embed, typically requiring some `iframe` or other hackery. See for instance how [Kongregate is now hosting HTML5 games](http://www.kongregate.com/html5-games).

Google Native Client might just be the modern ActiveX but it is used in some very interesting browser-based games in the Chrome Web Store.

Last but not least, lots of good games are not very advanced on the client-side, and will do most of the interesting stuff from a PHP/MySQL server (typically). So you might have to consider an offer for server-side hosting (something that is definitely compatible with lots of client-side technologies).

Comment: You are mixing server side (PHP) with client side technologies.

Comment: @Jonas Yes I am. Turn-based games that run mostly on a server and deliver static HTML are quite common, see for instance [Brass Online](http://brass.orderofthehammer.com/). I've no idea how this would integrate in a "website that hosts various online games" but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: -1 for Java applets.

Comment: @Yannbane Why -1 for Java? While there are unquestionably some security issues with the Java plug-in, it's a mature technology and an ostensibly cross-platform solution that quite a few users are still more than happy to run.  I fail to see (specific vulnerabilities aside) why Java is any less valid an answer here than Flash, and it seems pedantic to hold those vulnerabilities against the answerer.

Comment: I've posted a link to a very good Security SE answer where you will find your answer. Java is currently one of the most insecure technologies and you should not force your users to enable it. With every release there are critical vulnerabilities, and that's not going to change because of the way Java applets are designed to work.

Answer (score -5):

**Edit:** don't support Java. The web applets it provides are completely insecure and probably never will be good enough. There's a reason why it practically doesn't exist on the Internet anymore. I also suggest you disable Java (**not** JavaScript) in your browser too.

You're not interested in file formats. There are many types of those, and usually it's just text or some other binary format you shouldn't concern yourself over. You're interested in technology.

It's not up to your servers to support HTML5, JavaScript, or Flash. You simply need to send the file over the network, and make sure your website conforms to W3C standards.

The client's browser has to support various technologies.

Unless, of course, you're talking merely about *online* games, not necessarily on the WWW. For that, there are various combinations, and that makes this question too ambiguous.

Comment: -1 he said he wants to "looking into making a website that hosts various online games" - in order to do that, he has to choose what formats to support, because they all have different methods for embedding and different security implications.

Comment: And I have already instructed him on not supporting Java because of the security implications. Otherwise, he simply asked for us to list various file formats and explain how to "support them", but I have explained that the support part is mostly the concern of the client.

Comment: I feel like my answer is being downvoted only by offended Java programmers. Refer to [my comment](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26130/what-are-different-types-of-online-game-formats-besides-flash/47804#comment79745_26132). I don't hate Java, but it is insecure.

Comment: "I have explained that the support part is mostly the concern of the client" -> and that's what you are wrong about.

Comment: Point out how. The client has to support JavaScript, you merely send it over the network. The client has to support Flash, Java, and pretty much everything else suggested in this thread. My answer is getting downvoted only because I'm bad-mouthing Java. Don't you want your clients to be secure? Why would you force them to use an insecure product?

Comment: My downvote wasn't precisely because you're bad mouthing Java (although you failed to notice this, I dismissed it too), but because your vendetta against that option seems to have blinded you to what the question was and what is/is not an answer to that question.

Comment: also if you're thinking that putting Flash game and JavaScript games onto a website is the same, well, not really. Refer to the first two comments under my question.